# How do I make text appear in a window?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create a stopwatch in javascript, until I encountered a problem. When finishing the actual clock, I realized that the numbers were not displayed in the preview window, but instead, it was displayed in the console. Is there any way to make the text appear in the preview window?

At first, I tried to see if the "Prompt()" mechanic could fix it, but instead, it displayed an alert. Help!!

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("1");
}, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 1999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("2"); 
}, 2000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 2999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("3");
}, 3000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 3999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("4"); 
}, 4000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 4999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("5") 
}, 5000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 5999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("6") 
}, 6000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 6999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("7") 
}, 7000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 7999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("8") 
}, 8000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 8999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("9") 
}, 9000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 9999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("10") 
}, 10000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 10999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("11") 
}, 11000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 11999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("12") 
}, 12000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 12999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("13") 
}, 13000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 13999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("14") 
}, 14000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 14999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("15") 
}, 15000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 15999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("16") 
}, 16000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 16999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("17") 
}, 17000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 17999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("18") 
}, 18000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 18999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("19") 
}, 19000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 19999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("20")
}, 20000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 20999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("21")
}, 21000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 21999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("22")
}, 22000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 22999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("23")
}, 23000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 23999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("24")
}, 24000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 24999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("25")
}, 25000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 25999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("26")
}, 26000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 26999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("27")
}, 27000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 27999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("28")
}, 28000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 28999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("29")
}, 29000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 29999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("30")
}, 30000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 30999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("31")
}, 31000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 31999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("32")
}, 32000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 32999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("33")
}, 33000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 33999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("34")
}, 34000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 34999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("35")
}, 35000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 35999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("36")
}, 36000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 36999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("37")
}, 37000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 37999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("38")
}, 38000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 38999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("39")
}, 39000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 39999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("40");
}, 40000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 40999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("41"); 
}, 41000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 41999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("42");
}, 42000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 42999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("43"); 
}, 43000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 43999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("44") 
}, 44000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 44999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("45") 
}, 45000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 45999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("46") 
}, 46000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 46999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("47") 
}, 47000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 47999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("48") 
}, 48000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 48999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("49") 
}, 49000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 49999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("50") 
}, 50000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 50999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("51") 
}, 51000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 51999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("52") 
}, 52000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 52999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("53") 
}, 53000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 53999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("54") 
}, 54000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 54999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("55") 
}, 55000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 55999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("56") 
}, 56000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 56999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("57") 
}, 57000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 57999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("58") 
}, 58000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 58999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("59")
}, 59000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 59999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("60")
}, 60000);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear()
}, 60999);
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("Time is up!")
}, 61000);

setTimeout(function() {
  alert("Time is up!")
}, 62000);
```

Comment: We can't help you fix code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Sorry! I will add a code.

Comment: The code is a lot longer than this, but I am more concerned on how to make my code appear in the preview

Comment: *Which* preview?

Comment: There's not enough information there to help you. You need to add all relevant code - HTML, JS and CSS.

Comment: I am using a site called "Codepen" which allows you to see a preview window for your code.

Comment: Without any relevant HTML we cannot give you any specifics or code. However, if you want something displayed on your page you will likely be using the `querySelector` method to get the element on the page you want to display your information, then use the `innerHTML`, `innerText`, or `textContent` property of that element to set the value that will be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are looking to open at **modal** [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) ?

and you will be more efficient by using [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

some usefull references :

- [keydown_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event)
- [Keyboard_event_code_values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UI_Events/Keyboard_event_code_values)

sample code

```js
const
  btStart  = document.querySelector('#bt-start')
, msgDiag  = document.querySelector('#msg-dialog')
, pCounter = document.querySelector('#msg-dialog p')
, btDlgEnd = document.querySelector('#msg-dialog button')
, counterMaxVal  = 10  // or what ever, as 60...
  ;
btStart.onclick = () =>
  {
  let count = 1
    ;
  pCounter.textContent = count;
  btDlgEnd.classList.add('noVisible');
  msgDiag.showModal();                  // choose modal mode

  let refIntv = setInterval(()=>
    {
    pCounter.textContent = ++count
      ;
    if (count >= counterMaxVal)
      {
      clearInterval( refIntv );
      btDlgEnd.classList.remove('noVisible');
      }
    }
    , 1000); // this is just an aproximative delay, this is not one real second
  }
btDlgEnd.onclick = () =>  // end of dialog
  {
  msgDiag.close();
  }
document.onkeydown = evt =>
  {
  if ( msgDiag.open 
    && evt.key === 'Escape'
    ){
    evt.preventDefault();   // disable this 'Escape' event action
    }
  }
```

```css
.noVisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<menu>
  <button id="bt-start">start counter dialog</button>
</menu>

<dialog id="msg-dialog">
  <p>000000</p>
  <button class="noVisible">Time is up!</button>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Oh I see now. 
My only question is how to change the number each interval. I was thinking of just putting "+1" after the previous value, but it doesn't work. is there a way to increase the number after each interval? 
I am just learning how to code, so I don't know much.
What I am saying, is that I want to know how to increase the value each time.

Comment: @Mr.Biscuit  it's in my code: `++count`, a simple [prefixed increment operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment#prefix_increment)

Comment: sorry! I'm new.